# Computing $\int\frac{x^{e-1}+e^{x-1}}{x^e+e^x+e^e}dx$

Tags: calculus

How to Integrate this:
$$\int\frac{x^{e-1}+e^{x-1}}{x^e+e^x+e^e}dx \: ?$$
Is there any shortcut to integrate it simply?

What are the properties of "e" when we Integrate an expression with that 
I am really collapsed about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following substitution $u = x^e+e^x+e^e$ and $du=(ex^{e-1}+e^x)dx=e(x^{e-1}+e^{x-1})dx$.

You integral will reduce to

$$\int\frac{1}{eu}du=\frac{1}{e}\int\frac{1}{u}du=\frac{1}{e}\ln(u)+c=\frac{1}{e}\ln(x^e+e^x+e^e)+c$$

Where $c \in R$ is an arbitrary constant and $\ln(u)$ is the logarithm to the base $e$.

Comment: Is $$In=log_{e}?$$

Comment: Yes, i edited my answer.

Comment: I think Ln is short for log naturelle, which is french for natural log or something. Anyways yes, Ln is logarithm with base $e$.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithme_naturel

Comment: Any way Thank you very musch

Comment: You are welcome